# Keep/synch Adobe Digital Editions's notes, highlights and and bookmarks

Tags: pdf, ebook, drm, epub

I have bought a book and I'm using Adobe Digital Editions. I loved it for using PDF and ePub instead of proprietary formats and allowing us to store our books locally and read them offline.

I must use it at home and at work to read my book. First I tried to install it normally in HD and keep the book in pendrive, but I was losing notes and highlights when I removed the pendrive.

I then installed ADE directly in pendrive and now they aren't deleted anymore, but they are still not being shared. Highlights and notes I make at home are not available at work, and vice-versa.

Is there a proper way to keep/synch them thru different devices, and to avoid them being lost? It would be tragic to have some books in my library and a Windows reinstall make me lose all my notes.

Also, is there another ofline reader that supports ADE ebooks in Windows, or am I forced to use Adobe's one?

Comment: You migth get more answers on the new [Ebook.SE](http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/) site. If you're interested flag the question and request migration. http://meta.superuser.com/q/5336/95919